# Is it wrong to apply a background image in an html "A" element?

Tags: html, css

I used to have the following structure to hold a logo with a link inside a div:

```
    <a href="http://mysite.com">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </a>
```

with the following CSS:

```
    .logo {
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        height: 24px;
        background: url('logo.png') no-repeat;
    }
```

Is it wrong or there's any problem with compatibility if I remove the DIV and apply the 'logo' class directly to the A element? Just like this:

```
    <a href="http://mysite.com" class="logo"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing wrong with it. It's actually better to do it that way, less redundant markup.

Some other things to note:

- It's actually not valid for doctype other than `HTML5` to put a **block element** (in this case, the `div`) inside an `<a>`
- You should put a text inside the `<a>` for SEO/screen reader purpose and hide the text using `text-indent:-999px` and `overflow:hidden`. `display:block` is unnecessary as `float:left` implicitly sets it.

Comment: I use HTML5 doctype "<!DOCTYPE html>" so it is fine? And the link is just the top logo of the site, is it really needed this SEO purpose?

Comment: @RedCurley "what" is fine? Can you also clarify what you are asking about SEO?

Comment: To my knowledge, a background-image isn't a block element, and it is perfectly valid to make '<a>' a block element.

Comment: @RedCurley I edited my answer, hopefully it's clearer. Both your approach is valid if you are using HTML5 doctype, but second one is better. Just add a text in the `<a>`, style it and you are golden.

Comment: Sorry, you said that only with HTML5 header it is valid to put a block element inside an `<a>` and I get it wrong. So, it is more correct to just use an `<a>` element? And about SEO is it really necessary to put some text inside A tags?

Comment: @Llepwryd Please re-read my answer, it's got nothing to do with the background-image. It's the `div` inside the `a`. A block element inside an inline element.

Comment: I agree that you should use some text in the link for accessibility.

Comment: @RedCurley "correct" is not the term I'd use, both are "correct", but using just an `<a>` element is better because you really don't need that extra `<div>`, it doesn't serve a purpose. For SEO and screenreader, yes it is better to put a text in the `<a>`, otherwise crawler will see just an empty tag.

Comment: I get it but this link is just a link to the home of the site, I don't know if it's really important. Anyway, thanks for the answers.

Comment: @RedCurley So just put a text "Home" or the name of your site. It's easy, doesn't hurt and can only help.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked on Facebook and it's logo on the left-top corner is just like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in doing this. You will need to add display:block for dimensions to apply to a non block level element, but as for how the site is read and crawled, no it will not hurt you.

Comment: Well, I've tried on Chrome just using 'float: left' without 'display: block' and it seems to work just as a DIV, is it really necessary to use 'block'?

Comment: necessary is how you define it in this case. Just make sure it displays the same in all browsers.

Comment: @RedCurley Floated elements automatically become blocks.

Comment: it should be noted that float has a purpose as well, so don't just float for the sake of it happening to display block. Only float if you actually need to float. If you are not floating for a specific reason, just use display:block to apply dimensions to an inline element if needed

Comment: I actually float almost everything in my pages.

Comment: Good for you? If it achieves your goal then go for it. But if you're floating without doing it for the purpose of float then it's like using <article> or <aside> for everything instead of using tags for their purpose. It won't hurt you per say, but you may want to actually use things as intended. At the very least for maintainability should anyone else ever have to work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make img a block element using this:

```
 .logo {
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        height: 24px;
        background: url('logo.png') no-repeat;
        display:block;
    }
```

And as the others are saying it is safe to use an a-tag with a background but normally i have the logo in a div and an anchor on top. Good luck ; )

Comment: Making an element a block element in css is valid ; )

Answer (score 0):

It creates a major accessibility problem and is in direct violation of [Guideline 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#text-equiv) of the modern accessibility guidelines, WCAG 2.0: “Provide text alternatives for any non-text content so that it can be changed into other forms people need, such as large print, braille, speech, symbols or simpler language.” The content of the `a` element is empty, and a background image is displayed, when CSS is enabled and image loading is enabled; but there is no text alternative.

And you cannot specify a text alternative for a *background* image. Use a *content* image instead:

```
<a href="..."><img src="logo.png" alt="ACME"></a>
```

Here “ACME” is to be replaced by a descriptive name or abbreviation for the linked page.

By default, an image that is a link has a colored border, with the same color as link texts. You can remove it by using `border="0"` in the `img` tag or `a img { border: none }` in CSS.

Comment: `<a href="...">ACME</a>` with the bg image would by fine too from an SEO point of view.